# Difference in Clojure's record methods

Tags: performance, clojure, record

Okay, the title is not exactly what I was looking for, but it has to do  I found an interesting thing in the speed of record's member function access. I'll illustrate with this REPL session:

```clojure
==> (defprotocol Add (add [_]))
Add
==> (defrecord R [x y] Add (add [_] (+ x y)))
=.R
==> (let [r (->R 1 2)] (time (dotimes [_ 100000] (add r)))) ; Pure functional style
"Elapsed time: 19.613694 msecs"
nil
==> (let [r (->R 1 2)] (time (dotimes [_ 100000] (.add r)))) ; Functional creation, but with method call
"Elapsed time: 477.29611 msecs"
nil
==> (let [r (R. 1 2)] (time (dotimes [_ 100000] (.add r)))) ; Java-style
"Elapsed time: 10.051506 msecs"
nil
==> (let [r (R. 1 2)] (time (dotimes [_ 100000] (add r)))) ; Java-style creation with functional call
"Elapsed time: 18.726801 msecs"
nil
```

I can't really see the reason for these differences, so I'm asking that from you.

Comment: Please consider using criterium for this kind of test, it generally gives much more accurate results, and provides more useful information than a simple dotimes would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your second call is that Clojure compiler is unable to determine the type of `r` variable at compilation time, so it is forced to use reflections.

To avoid it you should add [type hint](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints):

```
(let [^user.R r (->R 1 2)] (time (dotimes [_ 100000] (.add r))))
```

or simply

```
(let [^R r (->R 1 2)] (time (dotimes [_ 100000] (.add r))))
```

and it'll be just as fast as Java-style method call.

---

If you want to easily diagnose such problems in your code, set `*warn-on-reflection*` flag to true:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
```

or add it to `:global-vars` section in your `project.clj` file:

```
:global-vars {*warn-on-reflection* true}
```

---

So, as you can see, without reflections method calls are a little bit faster than functional calls. But reflections could make method calls really slow.